# How does Stack Exchange determine 'Today's Featured Site'?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, featured-site

I wonder how SE reports the "Today's Featured Site" on the right side of its homepage. How does it consider a site as "featured"? is it the site with max number of views? or maybe max number of hot questions? what is it?

Comment: It is less exciting as you hoped for ...

Comment: uhum! if it is random, what's the point of reporting it then!!

Comment: Yeah, I agree but that is with most marketing/advertizing stuff, *what is the point*

Comment: The point is to expose people to different sites. If we chose by some metrics as you suggested, there would only ever be one site on that list, every single day...